# Generic Method Fails to Utilize Covariance on IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, covariance

I am wondering why the following code fails to compile, with the exception "*Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TImpl>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInterface>'*":

```
public static List<TInterface> Foo<TInterface, TImpl>(IEnumerable<TImpl> input)
    where TImpl : TInterface
{
    return input.ToList<TInterface>();
}
```

I know that I could change the return line to be `input.Cast<TInterface>().ToList()` instead, but want to understand why the code as written doesn't compile.  In my mind, it seems as though the compiler should be able to verify that *input* can be implicitly cast to *IEnumerable<TInterface>*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variance only works on classes.

Add `class,` to your constraint.

[Demo](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:preview/f:s/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0BhA9gG31QGNkxcIRMBxVCVAJzGIG4AoUSWRFDTAGUgBHdmwAOwAEb5mMFAEMyxGIJQAeACoBJCGgYAzecVQA+GADFcuTTr2HjAGhjb0Y/CYAUWgKIRg6RnlpVBtXdxhICWQASjYYeJgAdwALRlRnLTCYAC4YYnx5EBAnbV1Ge1Q2AG84hIZUZGAGCAiIKMwNXFVkGzKDI1MPaPYAXzi2IAA)